# Centering my bed on a 12" post protruding from a wall

Tags: drywall, structural, interior, renovation, design

I want to place my bed where the column is protruding from the wall in the center of the room. The post was installed by the previous owner during expansion. I hired a structural engineer to have this post removed but I also wanted a second opinion. How would you go about disguising this post to have a bed in front of it? Attached below is a render of my bedroom.

[image: Master Bedroom]

My approach was to install a very large drywall backdrop the width of my bed and decorate it with lamps or accent coloring. I feel that this would lower my home value because not everyone has the same size bed as me.

[image: Example of backdrop]

Update:

Here's how it would look! I removed the closet and shrunk down the second living room size. Let me know what you think, I'm interested.

[image: Concept]

Comment: I disagree that this will lower the home's value. IMO the best place for the bed is there, and the fill-around you've described will allow the bed in that location.

Comment: I don't see any issues with your solution, and agree with David about sizing - and I would also suggest replacing the top third with book shelves for additional storage :)

Comment: Frankly, I'd think that the loss of closet space in what appears to be a master bedroom is of _far_ greater consequence to resale value than the little bump-out in the wall (which looks good, IMHO). Unfortunately, since you seem to think otherwise, what your looking for are opinions, and they just don't fit well in the SE model.

Comment: @FreeMan I agree. It’s just that wall dividing to the other room is very thin. There is currently a jack and Jill door going into the other room. I wanted insulation between the wall dividing the closet. It was the previous owners design, it seems they cut a lot of corners. I could extend the closet out further but i don’t want to look at a wall when entering my room. What do you think? I really need some opinions on this because I been going back and forth all week.

Comment: [What _not_ to ask](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask) - "I really need some opinions..."

Comment: @FreeMan i moved the closet to the opposite side of the room to give the other room a larger closet space and allow for insulation between those walls. Do you think that was a valuable move? I sacrificed my second living room space to accommodate a larger closet in my master bed.

Comment: I like your idea.  Make the backdrop a bit bigger than a King so you can use it with any bed.   Add new power outlets to the new wall on both sides of the bed.  You could include alcoves, sconces, reading lamps .... whatever complements the look of the room.   You can avoid having night tables by including appropriate shelving and lamps inside the new wall.

Answer (score 3):

So that works well.

A couple of possibilities:

1. alcoves for storing bits with or without lamps
2. cupboards behind well access each side - again storage

But if you want the uncluttered look...

Comment: Thanks for your input, I’m going for a “minimalist” approach so I’ve been trying to work around putting cabinents and shelves in any rooms.

Comment: @user3630509 That's fine, hope it comes out how you want.

Answer (score 1):

I like your idea of bumping out the area on either side of the post. Just size it for a King bed and if you're worried about resale then don't make it too custom. Or sell your bed with the home.

Answer (score 0):

Just accept the presence of this 12" post protruding from the wall. It makes it easier to clean behind the bed.

Aren't there electrical receptacles on one side or both sides of this post? It would not make sense to cover those with some sort of panel.

Comment: If (big "if" as spacing could be such that receptacles are not affected) there are affected receptacles, they can easily be extended to match the new wall.

Comment: "ignore this post" - wouldn't it make more sense to delete it or remove that comment... Please clarify!

Comment: This is a valid concern that’ll have to talk to a licensed electrician about, I forgot about the receptacles. I can embed them into the wall. I’ll have to make enough space to make it flow well though.

Comment: You do not want anything immovable to obstruct access to receptacles. There can be a rat's nest of cords plugged into a receptacle behind a bed that doesn't ever get inspected and can be damaged by being pressed on by the head end of the bed. This projecting post saves you from that. It's a feature not a bug!